# Charles Proxy with Genymotion: monitoring https -> unreadable response

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, genymotion, charles-proxy

**The case:** I want to use Charles Proxy for debugging my requests to API on Genymotion. After setting up Genymotion(**Proxy: 10.0.3.2** and **Port: 8888**) I got unreadable response. After some search I found out that it could be related with the use of SSL. I successfully installed Charles certificate on my emulator from `http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl/`, and I still get such unreadable response.
 [image]

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280987/ssl-proxy-with-genymotion-and-charles) and [this guide](https://thezero.org/blog/2016/01/28/android_proxy_charles/) didn't help me much

Comment: you are seeing the SSL-encrypted traffic there. you need to do a man-in-the-middle with charles and install the certificate in the browser you are using to open genymotion

Comment: @fragmentedreality **install the certificate in the browser you are using to open genymotion** Sorry, but I'm not sure that I get it. I have installed certificate on my genymotion with local browser. Should I install this certificate for the my particular app? but how?

Answer (score 3):

1) You have to add the device certificate (which you have done).

2) You need to add locations to the SLL Proxying table.

From the menu: Proxy--->SSL Proxy Settings...--->SSL Proxying

Click Add.

In the Host box, put the site name to translate (use wildcards if needed). Example: *.mysite.com

Leave the Port blank.

Click OK.

Make sure Enable SSL Proxying is checked, and your host filter is also checked.

Click OK.

Restart Charles.